# How to update Teams Bot menu?

Tags: botframework, manifest, microsoft-teams

I have a bot that deployed in Azure. For distributing this bot I create a manifest file, where I add a menu with 3 items for a personal chat. I install this manifest by using the 'Upload custom app' option, and I see this menu in the message input control.
Then I install this manifest into the team, which, by plan, should use this bot, and provide a link for this installed bot for other users in this team. By this link, they can install this bot.

But right now I need to update the menu, that I created earlier.
I update manifest: change the menu and increase the version (just in case, should say - I tried and without increasing of version).
Then I remove the bot from the team and from my local Teams app and install it into the team and Teams again, but with an updated manifest.

But I still see the old menu even in my local Teams app, not to mention other users. Although in the 'About' tab is displayed increased version.

So, how to update this menu for all users, that using this bot?

Answer (score 0):

So it's important to remember that there are two contexts - the bot in a "personal" mode ( a 1-1 version where it appears in your "Chat" list and in the left menu) and then inside a team. The fact that the one instance (e.g. the "personal" version) is updating but not the other doesn't help, because they're separate installations.

What I would suggest is the following:

1. go to the Team settings ("Manage team" menu), then go to Apps in the top bar. Ensure that the bot is removed from there
2. be sure that wherever you are re-installing from is the correct, updated version. For instance, you might be **updating** the bot in App Studio, but **installing** from a previously side-loaded version in the tenant. As a result, for example here for testing, make sure that the bot's menu in App Studio is updated + correct, and then *install the bot into the correct team* directly from App Studio (under "Test and distribute" on the left menu, select "Install", then choose the small dropdown menu next to the big Add button, and choose the correct Team).